# How should the error message be formatted?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, question-quality

Let's say I have this error in plain text:

Error in quantile.default(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm, : missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE In addition: Warning message: In quantile(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm, names = FALSE, : NAs introduced by coercion

How should be formatted when asking, like a code:

```
Error in quantile.default(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm, : missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE In addition: Warning message: In quantile(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm, names = FALSE, : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Or like a quotation?

> Error in quantile.default(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm,
>   : missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE In
>   addition: Warning message: In quantile(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75),
>   na.rm = na.rm, names = FALSE, : NAs introduced by coercion

In this case I would go for the quotation because it is easier to read. But which is the official position if any of SO?

I have seen both, most questions seem to use code formatting, but sometimes I've seen them [use the quotation format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13019984/2886003).

Comment: This should really be a unique formatting button such as a quote or code in the editor.

Answer (score 10):

- If it is a descriptive error message, in real language, I would quote it.
- For a stacktrace or similar organised, ordered error set, I would format as code to preserve the layout for easy parsing.
- And for an error type such as "NullPointer" used in text, I would `wrap with backticks` to keep the flow of the text uninterrupted.

I might have used option 2 for your error adding in newlines to break up the message but I think it just comes down to personal choice. It's ok as long as it is legible and as AD7six mentions below, that it doesn't introduce unnecessary horizontal scrolling as it can be a nuisance to read.

```
Error in quantile.default(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm, :
    missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
In addition: Warning message:
    In quantile(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm, names = FALSE, :
    NAs introduced by coercion
```

Perhaps something like that.

Comment: Great, the same I do, but I will wait to know the opinion of the community :D

Comment: On a mobile device the pre-formatted example in this answer *needs scrolling to read it* - _don't_ pre-format text when it adds no value to do so.